# Peak Detector not capturing the peak

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have designed a peak detector to capture the peaks of high speed pulses. This is the circuit:[image: Peak detector circuit]

This is the waveform obtained on simulation:
[image]

Waveform when input peak is about 2.5 V:

[image]
Orange is PR3, output of peak detector. Blue is PR4, output of Op- Amp U1. Red is PR1, input pulse.
I use Comp_1 to discharge the cap C2, after the pulse has ended. This is done to capture peak of all the pulses (regardless of the value).

Could someone suggest how I can fix this issue?

Comment: @Trevor, it doesn't help. On the contrary, the value stored during pulse is further lower than the actual peak.

Comment: You're powering the op-amp from `VDC5V0`. Presumably this is 5.0 V. How close to the positive rail is LT1809 able to drive its output? Does the circuit work if the input peak is only at 2.5 V?

Comment: @ThePhoton, Yes VDC5V0 is 5V. I tested the op-amp as a unity gain buffer, it was able to follow the input without issue.  With a 2.63 V peak, there is a drop initially ( Vpeak= 2.54V). However due to bias current, the peak  increases to 2.68 V before the pulse ends.

Comment: When you did the buffer test, what was the load on the output? (Try with a load that will give a similar current to what will be needed in your final circuit)

Comment: I just ran the sim again, the load is 220 pF cap, with series resistor 33 ohm. Feedback taken at ouput of op-amp. Resistor is used to avoid settling issue. The output follows the input.

Comment: Looks like the cap just cant charge that fast... try a smaller cap

Comment: If you zoom in on the image it's obviously still charging when the diode turn off. That 220 in the feedback loop may be slowing you down too... not sure why its there to be honest.

Comment: @Trevor, the 220 pF is a compensation cap, without it I will have undamped response and the output of opamp will overshoot, capturing higher value than the peak.

Comment: Maybe so, but between that and the recovery time of the diode you have not left much window for the circuit to turn around with a fast rise time coming in.

Answer (score 1):

For high speed pulses, I would avoid amplifiers with fancy things in their feedback path.

Go back to the basic principles of how a diode or BJT work.  A diode or emitter follower driving a capacitor is a peak detector.  You can use a FET to reset the capacitor voltage to 0 to be ready for the next peak, or a resistor that bleeds off the voltage with a long enough time constant to not interfere with whatever you are trying to do.